# What is the default clipboard manager in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, clipboard

I don't care about panel plugins or programs such as xclip or xsel.

I just want to know : when I cut or paste something on Xubuntu, what program handles it?

Comment: [This article](http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt) and [this one](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) outline some important points about X's handling of its buffers and the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `/usr/bin/X` program.

Every program acts as  a X client for the X server.

As Michael Toren states: ["Copy-paste exists in all X Windows implementions, independent of the Window Manager"](http://michael.toren.net/mirrors/doc/X-copy+paste.txt).

Comment: Are you sure? Thanks to you I just read the X manual and I understood the clipboard functionnality was made through xclipboard. Am I wrong?

Comment: xclipboard doesn't implement the clipboard functionality. It is just another (primitive) GUI clipboard manager.